# Send an url to the socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following snippet of python code:

```
host = '127.0.0.1'  # listen to localhost
port = 8000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()
    if image:
        csock.send(image)
```

And if I image is a string like 'image.png' than everything is okay and I see 'image.png' on the webpage of the localhost that the server is listening to.

However, if the image is of the format 'http://image.com/image.png' than I the page doesn't show me anything. And I want the localhost display its name 'http://image.com/image.png'.

How can I send to socket the name of the image that has url format?

Comment: What is `image`?  It doesn't look you have it defined in the code above.  What are you using to access your server?  If it's a web browser you need to send the response twice.  First as HTML page with the link to your image second you send the image itself.  Of course you need to read and parse what client sends you first before sending the response.  The client will send either 'GET /'  first time and then GET /image.png second time.

Comment: `image` is just a string, which can be of format 'image.png' or 'http://image.com/image.png'. I just read it from the file; you can imagine that in the *while* loop I obtain the name of the image. And I need to display the **name** of the image, not the image itself! The image itself may not exist.

Comment: What are you using on the client side?

Comment: I have this code that listens to GET responses that I send in the browser.